# Get all index value of 1 from binary "01000111"

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary

I tried to get all the indexes from the binary like "01000111" so it should return an array [1,2,3,7];

I have tried this to get the index :

```
var getIndex1 = function(binary){
    var str = binary.toString();
    var indices = [];
    for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
        if (str[i] == "1"){
          indices.push(i);
        } 
    }
    return indices;
  };
```

when I tried to get the index using that function I got this :

```
return getIndex1("01000111"); // it returns [0,2,3,4]
```

I tried the same function to get all indexes of "s" from scisorss and it works fine. Anyone had this kind of problem? what I'm missing here? please help, and thanks.

Comment: Your function does **not** return `[0,2,3,4]` for the input `"01000111"`. It returns `[1,5,6,7]`. In any case the problem is that your code is counting from left-to-right instead of right-to-left.

Comment: wow that's weird? I tried this on freecodecamp but it return  [0,2,3,4] for the input "01000111"

Comment: is it because the browser? @Pointy

Comment: Just try running the code in your own browser. I can't check it at the site you mentioned because it seems to be broken.

Comment: @Pointy I tried to to the same thing in my computer using node, the result is the same  [0,2,3,4] for the input "01000111".

Comment: is it because of javascript can't find the index in string of binary? I dont know.

Comment: That is completely impossible. Run it in your browser, run it in Node, and you'll get `[1,5,6,7]`. If you're getting a different answer, then you're running different code than what you posted here.

Comment: Look at your input string: `"01000111"`.  Do you see a `1` at the beginning (left side) of the string? No.  Is there a `1` at the second position (index `1`)?  Yes, so that's the first number in the result array. There are then three zeros at indexes `2`, `3`, and `4`, and then `1` characters at indexes `5`, `6`, and `7`.

Comment: I feel stupid, thank you @Pointy, I was looking at wrong direction I was looking from the right to left. so I jut need to reverse the binary to get the result. you can answer this question so I can vote :D

Comment: Well I'm happy it's working for you now!  The answer  that somebody else provided is fine. Best of luck!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VfpdMCpJLJXIDF3hOsjR?p=preview).

The code you provided is returning `[1,5,6,7]`. Which is the expected behavior.

With the string `"01000111"`, indexes 1,5,6 and 7 have a value of `1`

If you want to go right to left, you should change your function to:

```
var getIndex1 = function(binary){
    var str = binary.toString();
    var indices = [];
    for(var i=str.length; i>0; i--) {
        if (str[i] == "1"){
          indices.push(str.length - i - 1);
        } 
    }
    return indices;
  };
```

Comment: looks like I found the problem in the comment but thanks

Comment: Might be late on this, for this code snip. In the for loop part of this function: you need to have `for(var i=str.length; i>=0; i--)`, the i need to be >= 0, othervise, it's going to miss checking the most left one.